# Error in adding extra meta box for woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding extra meta boxes to be called inside tabs in front end. This is added inside add new product page.But it gives error saying: Warning:

> call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class
>   'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Features_Advantages' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\mysite\wp-admin\includes\template.php on line 1048

screenshot:
[image]

I simply followed the way short description meta box added. Thus, I created a class file in this location:

```
C:\wamp\www\mysite\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\meta-boxes\class-wc-meta-box-features-advantages-.php
```

and the content looks like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product Features Advantages
 *
 * Replaces the standard excerpt box.
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @category    Admin
 * @package     WooCommerce/Admin/Meta Boxes
 * @version     2.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/**
 * WC_Meta_Box_Product_Features_Advantages Class.
 */
class WC_Meta_Box_Product_Features_Advantages {

    /**
     * Output the metabox.
     *
     * @param WP_Post $post
     */
    public static function output( $post ) {

        $settings = array(
            'textarea_name' => 'features_advantages',
            'quicktags'     => array( 'buttons' => 'em,strong,link' ),
            'tinymce'       => array(
                'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,blockquote,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,link,unlink,separator,undo,redo,separator',
                'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
            ),
            'editor_css'    => '<style>#wp-excerpt-editor-container .wp-editor-area{height:175px; width:100%;}</style>',
        );

        wp_editor( htmlspecialchars_decode( $post->post_excerpt ), 'features_advantages', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_features_advantages_editor_settings', $settings ) );
    }
}
```

Also added few more lines here: C:\wamp\www\mysite\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php inside add_meta_boxes() function.

```
add_meta_box( 'features_advantages', __( 'Product Features and Advantages', 'woocommerce' ), 'WC_Meta_Box_Product_Features_Advantages::output', 'product', 'normal' );
```

and this line inside remove_meta_boxes()

```
remove_meta_box( 'features_advantages', 'product', 'normal' );
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add in functions.php file not in plugin folder

add this code in your current active theme functions.php:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'product_details_add' );                                                      

add_action( 'save_post', 'product_details_save' );

function product_details_add() {
    add_meta_box( 'product_details', 'Product Details', 'product_details_call', 'product', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function product_details_call( $post ) {
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'product_details_noncename' ); 
    $field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'product_details_meta', false );
    wp_editor( $field_value[0], 'product_details_meta' );
}
```